# database-table with lots of booleans - how to find similar rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, comparison

I've got a database table with ~ 1000 boolean columns, how can I order them by similarity to a given row? First I thought about using Levenshtein and store everything as one string, e.g.

```
1001111100010101010101...
```

and then compare the other rows:

```
1010100010101010101000...
0010101011000010101010...
0010101100010101101011...
1111000101101110100010...
...
```

but I guess that's pretty expensive. Therefore I'd like to have all the values/flags stored in different columns:

```
1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ...
```

and compare it to other rows

```
1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ...
0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ...
0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ...
1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... 
...
```

Now I'm looking for a performant way to order the rows by the number of matching 1s.

What's a fast way for this? The table can contain hundreds of thounds of rows, therefore performance is an important issue.

Comment: try logic gates, it might be helful. http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/CAL/digital-logic/gatesfunc/index.html

Comment: but how to use them with mysql?

Comment: check this out, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't answer my question at all. I'm looking for a performant way to find similar rows, not equal ones.